# proxy configuration on angular app for production

Tags: angular, deployment

proxy configuration for development is working  it isn't working for production version of app

worked with "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json" and code below

```
{
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "api_url",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      },
      "changeOrigin":true
    }
  }
```

did not worked for production...

Comment: Do not use `ng serve` on production! It's a warning repeated many times by the Angular team in console messages, documentation and GitHub issues.